# Show jwplayer buffer on console

Tags: jwplayer

I am trying to debug one of my aplications, and I am trying to get the current buffer printed to console. However, this only returns "undefined".

```
jwplayer('video-wrp2').setup({
    "flashplayer": JWPLAYER,
    "file": VIDEO1,
    "skin": PLAYER_SKIN,
    "width": 1000,
    "height": 568,
    "controlbar": "none",
    "autostart":true,
    "image":IMAGE1,
     events:{
        onBufferChange: function(e) {
                console.log(e.buffer);
            }
        }
    });
```

What is the right way to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is this running?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer : http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/YgjYW/5/ check it here, I too dont understand why it is coming as undefined, am i doing something wrong

Comment: @amelzer : did any of below, answers your question ?

Comment: @amelzer : which jwplayer version are you using ?

Comment: I haven't been following this issue, sorry. It seemed to be a problem that the jwplayer was no running on the same domain as was the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using JWPlayer 6, change your code to

`jwplayer('video-wrp2').setup({
    file: VIDEO1,
    skin: PLAYER_SKIN,
    width: 1000,
    height: 568,
    autostart:true,
    image:IMAGE1,
    debug: true
    });`

Maybe it will work also in JWPlayer 5.

**Example** : http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/YgjYW/7/

Comment: is there a parameter "debug":"true" ....  i am seeing it for first time. do you have any reference for this

Comment: I don't have and reference for this parameter but it works with jwplayer 6

Comment: didnt work for me....try editing here .... http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/YgjYW/5/.... what it actually does ???

Comment: what actually happens if i make it true ?

Comment: Wow :D (y) ... you taught me something new !!! thanks ..... http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/YgjYW/7/

Comment: could you pls edit your answer and add my jsfiddle link sothat i can upvote u

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is wrong here, but it does shows `undefined`.I too tried and I am also getting `undefined`
However, you can use other method getbuffer(). Source :[Jwplayer API](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28850/using-the-javascript-api) and [javascript-api-reference](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference)

```
jwplayer('playerwnqZpIQLUFAE').setup({
        file: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abjAqvdGZgM',
        image: 'https://www.longtailvideo.com/content/images/jw-player/lWMJeVvV-876.jpg',
        width: '100%',
        stretching : 'exactfit',
        aspectratio: '4:3',
        fallback: 'false',
        primary: 'HTML5',
        events:{
        onBufferChange: function(callback) {
                console.log(callback.buffer);
                console.log(jwplayer('playerwnqZpIQLUFAE').getBuffer());
            }
        }
    });
```

: [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/YgjYW/5/)

This is working and i can see the buffer progress.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that:

`callback.buffer` - Does not exist. Which is why it is saying undefined.

So this call will not work:

```
console.log(callback.buffer);
```

However, this call works fine:

```
getBuffer();
```

So this console.log command will work just fine:

```
console.log(jwplayer('playerwnqZpIQLUFAE').getBuffer());
```

Comment: but jwplayer api says ... http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference/ .... variable exist ... why it doesn`t exist , does it have different name

Comment: That section is the "buffer" section, there are only two options there, "getBuffer()" and "onBufferChange(callback)", and here is where you would use the "buffer" attribute - onBufferChange(callback)
    Fired when the currently playing item loads additional data into its buffer. Event attributes:

        buffer (Number): Percentage between 0 and 100 of the current media that is buffered.

Comment: No problem, any time.